# Trazendo registros somados de outra tabela em uma nova consulta

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma tabela "tbA" onde a coluna primária "a1" precisa ser referenciada pela tabela "tbB" pela coluna "fk_a1"

**tbA**

```
id | nome   |
---+------+--
1,  'aaaa'
2,  'bbbbb'
3,  'cccc'
4,  'ddddd'
```

**tbB**

```
id | fk_a1 |  valor_1 | valor_2 |
---+-------+----------+----------
1,     2,     500.00,    100.00
2,     1,     150.00,    200.00
3,     1,     100.00,    50.00
4,     3,     10.00,     0.00
5,     3,     100.00,     20.00
```

Considerando que o relacionamento entre as duas tabelas é algo como

```
SELECT * FROM tbA a LEFT JOIN tbB b ON b.fk_a1 = a.id
```

Feita essa relação preciso listar os registros considerando que a tabela principal é a tbA e os valores somados da tbB virão na listagem assim

```
id | nome |  soma_1 | soma_2 |
---+------+---------+---------
1,  'aaaa',   250.00,  50.00
2,  'bbbbb',  500.00,  100.00
3,  'cccc',   110.00,  20.00
4,  'ddddd',  0.00,    0.00
```

Não sei exatamente como fazer isso, obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seria algo +- assim:

```
SELECT id,nome,SUM(valor_1) as soma_1, SUM(valor_2) as soma2 
FROM tbA a JOIN tbB
ON b.fk_a1 = a.id, GROUP BY a.id
```

Removi o `LEFT` pois nesse caso não teria efeito.

Comment: No meu caso era necessário o left pois também preciso trazer registros que não existem da tabela filha, obrigado pela ajuda, funcionou perfeitamente :)